# Pandas - df.columns truncated

Tags: python, pandas

The output for df.columns is truncated.

```
>>> df.columns
```

**Output**

> Index(['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4', 'column5',
>   'column6', 'column7', 'column8', 'column9', 'column10',
>
> ...
>
> 'column294', 'column295', 'column296', 'column297', 'column298',
>   'column299', 'column300', 'column301', 'column302', 'column303'],
>   dtype='object', length=303)

The example dataframe has 303 column names. Is there a pandas setting that would allow me to see all column names?

I tried changing max rows and columns but that isn't it. 
Example setting changes I tried:

```
pd.options.display.max_rows=200
pd.options.display.max_columns=200
```

Comment: If you just need to see, `df.columns.tolist()` would do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either of these would work:

```
df.columns.values
```

or

```
list(df.columns)
```

or

```
list(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually as simple as:

```
list(df)
```